# RichTextBlock - cannot change cursor from IBeam

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

In Windows 8.1 Apps, I am trying to make my mouse cursor an arrow when it is over a RichTextBlock. I have a really simple way of demoing the issue:
1. Create a new Blank Project.
Change the MainPage.xaml to the following:`

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <RichTextBlock>
        <Paragraph>Hello World
            <LineBreak/>
            <LineBreak/>
            <LineBreak/>
            Hello World
            <LineBreak/>
            <LineBreak/>
            <LineBreak/>
            Hello World
        </Paragraph>
    </RichTextBlock>
</Grid>
```

`

2) On MainPage.xaml.cs Change the constructor to be:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new CoreCursor(Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursorType.Hand, 1);
    }
}
```

When you load into the application, the Mouse cursor will be a Hand UNTIL you move it, then it will be an IBeam. I have tried using WinRT XAML Toolkit (1.5.4.3) FrameworkElementExtensions.SystemCursor as well, but to no avail... Is there any way around this? A reference for when you would use something like this would be the Wikipedia Windows 8 App.

I am running Windows 8.1 and the target for the project is also set to Windows 8.1

Comment: I did just find something out though.... IF you set the RichTextBlock to isTextSelectionEnabled="False", it will no longer cause the IBeam to show up... I also tried the same value on a TextBlock and am having the exact same results... I need to retain the ability to copy text however. Again, using the Wikipedia app as an example.